# change colour of specific row in datagridview if text in field says "No"

Tags: database, vb.net

This is my code:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim value = Val(row.Cells(9).Value)
        If value = "no" Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "no" to type 'Double' is not valid.'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your `DataGridView1.Columns(9)` contains strings, you can't pass them through function `Val()`, it expects objects that could be converted to the type `Double`

Comment: `Val` always returns a double.  If the cell contains text, use `.ToString`.  There is no need to loop thru the control though - use the CellFormatting even to do them as needed.

Comment: @Plutonix do you mean something like this?                         For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If (row.Cells(9).Value.ToString() = "no") Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next

Comment: More or less.  Depending on the source, you may need to check for DBNull or and empty string.  But again, looping is suboptimal - if the result can change it wont be dynamic.  An event will fire when the data changes

Comment: not sure why this has been down voted to be honest? have I not asked a valid question???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Val` because that's converting your value to a Double. Use `ToString` to convert it to a string, then compare that to "no"

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row IsNot Nothing _
        AndAlso row.Cells IsNot Nothing _
        AndAlso row.Cells(9) IsNot Nothing Then
        If If(row.Cells(9).Value, "").ToString().ToUpper() = "NO" Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf row.Cells(9).Value.ToString().ToUpper() = "YES" Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I would upvote but don't have enough rep!

Comment: When I use this code and run it, I get this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Hmm, I really didn't introduce anything new compared with your original code. What line is the exception being thrown on?

Comment: its being thrown on this line: If row.Cells(9).Value.ToString() = "no" Then

Comment: And what exactly is *Nothing* at that point? You can put some logic in to check that it is not *Nothing* before using it

Comment: It is either `row.Cells(9)` or `row.Cells(9).Value`

Comment: it's impossible to be nothing.. the field either says "yes" or "no". there is no capacity to leave it null

Comment: if i remove .tostring() then the program runs but the row doesn't change colour

Comment: Hi, @IanProbets, I believe you should accept djv 's answer.

Comment: @VBobCat it's not working and the guidelines state that you should not "accept" an answer if it has worked. In that case it has not and therefore my not accepting the answer reflects that.

Comment: Ok, just have in mind "No" and "no" are not equal strings and this might, as I perceive, be the sole cause it didn't work.

Comment: @VBobCat 'For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells(9).Value.ToString() = "No" Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            ElseIf row.Cells(9).Value.ToString() = "Yes" Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green

            End If
        Next' This is what I have in there at the moment and I get the object reference exception

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually, the property **.Value** may evaluate *Nothing* if that cell is empty or bound to a *null* field. Testing for `String.Equals(row.Cell(9).Value, "no", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` may seem monstrous compared to a plain = operator, but is a more robust way of accomplishing this verification.

Comment: But @VBobCat, *it's impossible to be nothing.. the field either says "yes" or "no". there is no capacity to leave it null - Ian Probets*

Comment: Anyway, Ian, I edited my answer. This should work for you.

Comment: I mentioned `It is either row.Cells(9) or row.Cells(9).Value` 3 hours ago. You could help us, and yourself, with some debugging - a little elbow grease.

Comment: Ok. Let's see. Is your DataGridView allowing users to insert new rows? If so, there will always be an empty row at the end of the collection, which does have null fields because it was not filled yet. That being your case, you can test the boolean property **dgv.IsNewRow** and skip it before testing its cell's content. I hope it helps.

Comment: I added a null coalescing operator on value, should catch all